# Grafana cannot resolve variable

Tags: grafana, promql, grafana-variable

I am using a dashboard variable name `$project` which can be `project_A`, `project_B` or `All`(or `*`) in Grafana.

Now, I want to write a query like

```
sum by (uri,status,method)(
 rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{team="myTeam",uri!="/actuator/prometheus",uri!="/actuator/health",project="$project"}[10m])  / 
 rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{team="myTeam",uri!="/actuator/prometheus",uri!="/actuator/health",project="$project"}[10m]) 
)
```

This is giving me no output when I am setting `$project=All`. I am assuming this is because it cannot resolve the variable `$project` in both the functions because for a specific `$project` value it is successfully giving me output.

Am I guessing correct? What is the workaround of it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
project="$project"
```

To:

```
project=~"$project"
```

Comment: Could you "accept" the answer then?